# Making my game object bounce forever?

Tags: swift, game-physics

So I am trying to make a ping pong game and I am able to get the ball moving and bouncing but the ball slows down. Whats the code to keep the balls velocity at a constant? Here's what I got:

```
  var ball = SKSpriteNode()
var enemy = SKSpriteNode()
var main = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {



    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width)
    ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    enemy = self.childNode(withName: "enemy") as! SKSpriteNode
    main = self.childNode(withName: "main") as! SKSpriteNode

    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 20))

    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 1

    self.physicsBody = border

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.2))
    }
}


  override  func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

        enemy.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ball.position.x, duration: 1.0))
}
```

}

My physics settings are set to the following:

[physics definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqK7i.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the restitution to zero.

Comment: Maybe try with a linear / angular damping of 0 ?

Comment: @Zouch that actually did the trick! Thank you. Something so simple overlooked. Thanks for your help!